# Area and Centroid of Polygon: pracma

Tags: r, geometry, polygons

I am using the R package pracma to compute the area and centroid of polygons with between 3 and 5 vertices. I know the manual explains cases when the area is negative, I don't quite understand this. Furthermore, the centroids in these cases are not what I am hoping to get.

The problem I am running into is that my program may generate polygons with vertices correctly ordered vertices, but in a manner which gives negative areas:

```
library(pracma)
xs<-c(0,1,1)
ys<-c(0,1,0)
poly_center(xs,ys)
polyarea(xs,ys)

xs<-c(1,1,0)
ys<-c(0,1,0)
poly_center(xs,ys)
polyarea(xs,ys)

xs<-c(1,0,1)
ys<-c(0,0,1)
poly_center(xs,ys)
polyarea(xs,ys)
```

Would someone be able to suggest a generalizable method (ie any number of vertices) for sorting the vertices so that I always get a positive area and expected centroid?

Comment: This is just an attempt to explain the cases of negative areas: Usually, the area of a polygon is negative when the points defining the polygon are ordered in a mathematically negative sense. In this case, where all points lie in the (x,y) plane, a mathematically positive orientation is given when the loop goes in a counterclockwise direction (if you look at the polygon from the top, along the negative z-direction) if you connect the points of the polygon in the order in which they are defined; and negative if the direction of the loop is clockwise.

Comment: I found this solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978642/how-to-sort-vertices-of-a-polygon-in-counter-clockwise-order. I just dont understand how I compute the angle from "each vertex to the center point"? What is the angle relative to?

Comment: As far as I understand the text, the angle they are referring to is the one between the line defined by the central point and the vertex[i] on one hand and the line defined by the central point and the vertex[i+1] on the other. Basically, you connect neighboring vertices to the central point and you compute the angle at the apex.